# skip or check null values in DSL query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, vega

using elasic search query in order to calulate an api, therefore I am using the bucket_script like below:

```
bucket_script: {
                  buckets_path: {
                    succ_req: response_recieve>sum_init
                    total_req: response_attemp>sum_init
                  }
                  script: "params.succ_req / params.total_req *100000 "
                }
```

then using the query to draw  a line using vega in kibana, the proble is that with "params.total_req" the return value is null therefor the visual shows up "Infinite extent for field "... how can check if the value is zero then do not calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
 script: "params.total_req != 0 ? (params.succ_req / params.total_req * 100000) : 0"
```